# How to set only ONE element in an array in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array saved on my firebase, like this:

```
matches:[ {match:{id:1,data:...}}]
```

I want to save just one item on firebase at this array. For example, my match have id:32. I want to find it on the array saved in firebase, and change it.

Im trying to make this. But Im thinking that this is VERY UGLY to make a request to the firebase, copy the array, and save the entire array again.

```
const ref = `/users/${currentUser.uid}/matches`;
      var list = [];
       firebase.database().ref(ref).on('value',  function (snap) { list = snap.val(); });

  if (list.length > 0) {
    const indexToUpdate = list.findIndex(k => k.name == match.name)
    if (indexToUpdate >= 0) {
      list[indexToUpdate] = match;

      return dispatch => {

         firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/matches`)
          .set(list)
          .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: MATCH_UPDATE, payload: match });
          });

      };
    }
  }
```

Any light?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `/users/${currentUser.uid}/matches/${indexToUpdate}/` Firebase stores arrays as object and converts it back to array when it comes back to the client if the keys are ordered numerically correctly and `.set(match)` instead of `.set(list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
const indexToUpdate = list.findIndex(k => k.name == match.name)
```

Is a dead giveaway that your data structure is not ideal.

Consider storing the matches under their name, prefixing it with a string to prevent the array coercion that Kenneth mentioned. So:

```
matches
  match1
    date: "2018-06-14..."
    ...
  match2
    date: "2018-06-16..."
    ...
```

With this you can look up the node for a match without needing a query. It also prevents using an array, which is an anti-pattern in Firebase precisely because of the reason you mention.

For more on this, see the classic Firebase blog post on [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase stores arrays as object and converts it back to array when it comes back to the client if the keys are ordered numerically correctly

But basically it should be able to work the same where you make your path up to the object you want to update.

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/matches/${indexToUpdate}`)
  .set(match)
  .then(() => {
    dispatch({ type: MATCH_UPDATE, payload: match });
  });
```

Comment: But the index to update isnt the position in array? 

For example, my match has id:2 but is in the position 0 of the array at my firebase. How can I find the position of this array, if not checking the id?

Comment: the index to update should be the position in the array. `const indexToUpdate = list.findIndex(k => k.name == match.name)` You already found the index here.

Comment: So, I need to fetch the array first, get the index, and then set, right?

Comment: Yup you need to get the array first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the ID of the item you are trying to set by ID in the URL

```
     firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/matches/32`)
      .set(list)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: MATCH_UPDATE, payload: match });
      });
```

Also, use snap.key to get the ID you need if index isn't working.

Comment: I uploaded a Screen shot of my firebase: 

Te question is, how can I set a match with "match.name==2". His index in the array is 1 in this case

Comment: You need snap.key, not just snap.val()